# how to dump DNS cache on a Linux client?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, solaris

Like the cache of nscd daemon.  I suspect the daemon does not do its work, I mean, not caching at all since it failed the query right after I stopped the name server.

Answer (score 0):

I have always heard to restart nscd via `/etc/init.d/nscd restart` but some systems to not have nscd daemons.

Comment: You need to install/start nscd daemon yourself. It seems not a default service. BTW, on Windows this is so easy. Just call ipconfig /showdns.  Not sure why this is so hard for nscd.  I've googled a lot without luck.